# Image Recognition ApI in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app that help user to recognize image.Is there any api in android so that i  can use it for image recognition.Image recognition means user take picture of any thing and application tell which image user taken .please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The company I work for, [Moodstocks](http://www.moodstocks.com/), provides such an API. It is [SaaS](https://developers.moodstocks.com/register) with a HTTP API, and we offer SDKs for [Android](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-sdk) and IOS that makes integrating it in an application easy.

Feel free to ask more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Camfind](https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/CamFind#!documentation)

Here's an example image that was uploaded, and the API's response below it -

#### Image Request

[image]

#### Image Response

```
{
   "name": "crystal geyser bottle",
   "status": "completed"
}
```